# Subnet parameter doesnt accept list as an input in cloud formation template aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, devops

I have a nested template setup and I am trying to pass the subnet values to the child ELB template. However , I keep getting `Value of property Subnets must be of type List of String` error.
This is how I am setting the value in the parent template:

```
ELBSubnetAZ: "subnet-*****,subnet-****"
```

This is how I am passing the value to the child template:

```
ELBSubnetAZ: !FindInMap [ AccountSettings, !Ref "ChefServerRegion", ELBSubnetAZ ]
```

This is how I am using the value in child template:

```
ELBSubnetAZ:
 Description: "ELB Subnet 1"
 Type: "List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>"
```

I also tried:

```
 ELBSubnetAZ:
  Description: "ELB Subnet 1"
  Type: CommaDelimitedList
```

In the resources:

```
  Subnets:
      - !Ref ELBSubnetAZ
```

It all works fine if I only pass a single value of subnets from the parent template and accept as a string variable in the child.
What am I missing?

Comment: The problem seems to be in your parent template. Can you please post a larger snippet, particularly the snippet where you're passing the subnet ids to the child stack?

Comment: @spg I am not doing much in my parent template except for passing these values , also I didnt define any parameter type in parent template , its just passing values.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem. 
My original AWS CF template for deploying an ELB was:

```
Parameters:
  ELBSubnetID:
    Type: 'List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>'
    Description: Subnet ID for ELB
Resources:
  MyLoadBalancer:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer'
    Properties:
      Listeners:
        - LoadBalancerPort: '80'
          InstancePort: '80'
          Protocol: HTTP
      Subnets:
        - !Ref ELBSubnetID
```

When I used the template to create a stack in AWS CF, it threw this error message:

```
Value of property Subnets must be of type List of String
```

I fixed the **Subnets** properties section in the template as follows and then I was able to create the stack successfully:

```
Parameters:
  ELBSubnetID:
    Type: 'List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>'
    Description: Subnet ID for ELB
Resources:
  MyLoadBalancer:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer'
    Properties:
      Listeners:
        - LoadBalancerPort: '80'
          InstancePort: '80'
          Protocol: HTTP
      Subnets:
        - !Join
          - ','
          - !Ref ELBSubnetID
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I solved it :

I didnt make any changes in the parent template , but in the child template I received the values as String and then split the string in to list using Fn::Split function. Luckily , Fn::Split function output returns List.

```
ELBSubnetAZ:
  Description: "ELB Subnets"
  Type: String
```

In my resource, This is how I am splitting it :

```
Subnets: { "Fn::Split" : [ ",", { "Ref":"ELBSubnetAZ" } ] }
```